# How to make a single quote attribute value in the output xml

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

while I'm converting the below xml file, its converted into as double quotes in the output:

My Input XML:

```
<p outputclass="Center">Type</p>
```

XSL I Used as:

```
   <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass = 'Center']">
      <div class='center'><p>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p></div>
   </xsl:template>
```

Output I'm getting as:

```
<div class="center"><p>Type</p></div>
```

But I need the output as in single quotes

```
<div class='center'><p>Type</p></div>
```

In the input I gave in single quote, But while conversion it turned into double quotes. Because of that double quotes the error is occurring the Json conversion. Can anyone please tell me how to get single quote or else Is we need to changes might be necessary. I'm using XSLT 2.0 and saxon-PE 9.6.0.7.

Please provide me some suggestion

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160948/using-xslt-to-create-json-output-single-quote-conversion-xml-to-json?rq=1 - though that doesn't have an accepted answer, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any XML Serializer that gives you control of whether single or double quotes are used as attribute delimiters. Certainly Saxon doesn't. If there's an application that consumes XML and requires one or the other, then that application is seriously buggy and is probably best avoided.

Comment: Thanks for your time @MichealKay. Its not the problem in this conversion. While I'm converting the converted XML to Json, the Json file is not getting validation due to the double quotes. That's the problem.

Comment: How are you converting the XML to JSON?

Comment: If you're embedding lexical XML (or anything else for that matter) in JSON strings, then double quote characters need to be escaped as `\"`.

Comment: I decided to add a serialization option saxon:single-quotes="yes" to the next Saxon release.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay